# .NET in WinForms, why my MenuStrip has no border or color?

Tags: .net, menu

This is a really simple question but I can't find anything... I have a windows form with a MenuStrip. The MenuStrip has the same color as the windows and there is not line or border... My "File" menu seems like a label that I put at the top of my form. I mean, when you open Notepad, the menu at least has a different color than the rest, it looks like a menu. How do I do that?

Comment: Feature, not a bug, do play with the RenderMode property to see if the choices there are more to your liking.  To use the exact same menu component that Notepad uses right-click the toolbox > Choose Items > select MainMenu.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't saw this as a bug though. I don't get what you mean by "right-click the toolbox > Choose Items > select MainMenu". If I click on the menuStrip, then on items in the properties I get a dialog window with the menu on the left and the same properties on the right.

Comment: The toolbox that you use in the designer, the one where you got MenuStrip from and also has Button, Checkbox, etc.

Comment: Right, I looked at it and I don't have MainMenu. Even in the "All windows forms" group, and even when I search. I use Visual Studio Community 2017.